# Move repo from plain git to GitLab server

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

I have two servers, an older server running plain `git` with three repositories under `/opt/`. These projects are now to be moved over to a new server where I choose to run `gitlab` for the sake of the GUI and to be able to invite friends to learn programming and have an easier place to view and manage projects.

However, when moving over I want to keep the revisions of my old code bases. Somehow I thought just doing `scp -r old-server.net:/opt/project.git /gitlab/` would suffice but this fails.

I navigated to `gitlab` and created a new repo just to get the folder structure which created a wiki and a code-folder called `/gitlab/project.git` with the same folder structure as it is on the old server (without the code obviously) and the project loads fine in `gitlab`, but then i did `rm -rf project.git` and did the `scp ...` and now i get a `500 We're sorry, but something went wrong.`.

My guess is that the revisions and perhaps an URL in the server-folder is wrong, but I can't find anything by going through the files manually or via the docs on gitlab.

Anyone done something similar?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the most simple basic solutions work... **permissions**, always check your permissions.

```
chown -R git.git /gitlab/project.git/
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the new gitlab remote to your existing repository and push:

> git remote add gitlab url-to-gitlab-repo
>
> git push gitlab master

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a few repos you want to include on your GitLab instance.

GitLab provides a bulk method to do this. I added about 250 repos with no issues.
Copy your git files to a new location on your GitLab server I will use a directory named 'import'. You can add 'XXX' (or even XXX/YYY) if you need sub location within your project:

```sh
# Use sudo as needed, but it's important to do this
# using the same username than the final GitLab repo.
rsync -av /your/repo/location/* ./import/XXX
# give GitLab  full access
chown git:git ./ -R
# Later GitLab will modify the source and turn into a bundle
chmod 02777 -R ./*.git
# now the real work. Note that the source is import and not import/XXX
gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos['./import/']
```

Now refresh your GitLab gui and the imported projects will be visible.
In my case, I have some old hooks, now deprecated on GitLab, so, I bulk deleted all on the newly created git files. (otherwise your will receive an error when pushing).